# mysql collation is fine for phpmyadmin but not for sql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, terminal, collation

i am having a database where i store both greek and english strings using collations : `"greek_general_ci"` and `"utf8_general_ci"` from phpmyadmin everything works fine ! 
but using mysql comand from terminal, or mysql_query from php i get some "?", do you have any idea why this happends ? 
in the meanwhile everything is fine from phpmyadmin !

i have to note that i need sometimes to use english , so a collation that supports only greek may not be much helpful, but i believe that it is not matter of the collation

also i have to say that i use this in my html to display greek characters :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

thank you

Comment: use utf8 for everyting

Comment: i did , i have two db's for testing one with utf8_general_ci and one greek_general_ci , but it looks like none of these are working :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: You are barking up the wrong tree. Your problem is not collation (or you have not yet found out so), but encoding.

- in the tables
- on your connection

I recommend you start debugging by putting a query like `SET NAMES 'UTF8'` at the start of your PHP scripts. Quite likely, this will make the immediate problem "go away", giving you a foot in the door for a more permanent fix.

Comment: if we just put away for a moment my php scripts, why it does work from phpmyadmin and not from terminal session ? :?

Comment: Most possibly, because phpMyAdmin does exactly that.

Comment: Ofcourse sending `SET NAMES 'UTF8'`works from a terminal session as well - provided your terminal **is** UTF8 ...

Comment: i just understand what you mean ! thank you ! that worked perfect for me :D !